# Выскакивает ошибка У объекта нет атрибута "comment_set"

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста!При добавлении комментов к одной из моих страниц на сайте выскакивает ошибка  У "Chat"объекта  нет атрибута "comment_set".до этого у меня была страница со статьями,там все комменты отображались и добавлялись без ошибок
Вот их модели:
#Статьи

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField("название статьи",max_length = 60)
    article_text = models.TextField("текст статьи",max_length = 3000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("дата публикации")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title
    
    
    def date(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))

    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'

#Комменты к статьям 
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 50)
    comment_text = models.CharField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

во views

```
def detail(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)  
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')    

    test2 = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]

    return render(request,'articles/detail.html',{'article': a, 'test2': test2})

#Для отображения Комментов
def add_comment(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)      
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')
    a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])    

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)))
```

И вот urls(ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ)

```
path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
path('<int:article_id>/add_comment/', views.add_comment, name = 'add_comment'),
```

Тут они отображаются(шаблон)

```
<h1 id = article_title>{{article.article_title}}</h1>

<h2 id = article_text>{{article.article_text}}</h2>

<em id = article_pubdate>{{article.pub_date}}</em> 

<h2 id = comment_name>Комментарии:</h2>

<hr id = 'hr_one'>

{% if test2 %}
     {% for c in test2  %}
    <p>
        <strong id = name_comment>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
        <p id = comment_text_article>{{c.comment_text}}</p>
    {% endfor  %}    
    </p>
{% else %}
<h2 id = 'comment_notfound_text'>Комментарии не найдены,станьте первым :)</h2> 
{% endif %}

<hr id = hr_two >

<!--КНОПКИ ОТПРАВКИ КОММЕНТОВ-->
<form action="{% url 'articles:add_comment' article.id %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}
<input id = 'input_name' type = 'text' required placeholder="Введите имя", name = 'name'><br><br>
<textarea name="text" required placeholder="Текст комментария" id="input_comment_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<button id = 'input_button' type = 'submit'>Добавить комментарий</button>
</form>
```

Вот и у меня есть еще другие модели(похожие на предыдущие),но при добавлении комментов выскакивает ошибка

Вот модели:

```
#Чат
class Chat(models.Model):
    title_chat = models.CharField("Название чата",max_length = 60)  
    chat_text = models.TextField("Описание чата", max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_chat

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Чат'

#Добавление комментов к чату
class Chat_text_add(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 30)
    comment_text = models.TextField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Добавление комментов к чату'
```

Вот views

```
def chat1(request,article_id):
    try:
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = article_id)
    except:
        raise Http404('Комменты в чате не найдены')  
   # test3 = b.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request,'articles/detail2.html',{'b': b,'title':'Заголовок'})  

def AddComment_inChat(request,article_id):
    try:
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = article_id)
    except:
        raise Http404('Комменты в чате не найдены')    
    
    b.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])     
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('articles:detail2', args = (b.id,)))
```

Вот urls

```
path('<int:article_id>',views.chat1,name = 'chat1'),
path('<int:article_id>/AddComment_inChat',views.AddComment_inChat,name = 'AddComment_inChat')
```

Тут они отображаются(шаблон)

```
<h1 id = article_title>{{b.title_chat}}</h1>

<h2 id = article_text>{{b.chat_text}}</h2>



{% if test3 %}
     {% for i in test3  %}
    <p>
        <strong id = name_comment>{{i.author_name}}</strong>
        <p id = comment_text_article>{{i.comment_text}}</p>
    {% endfor  %}    
    </p>
{% else %}
<h2 id = 'comment_notfound_text'>Комментарии не найдены,станьте первым :)</h2> 
{% endif %}


<!--КНОПКИ ОТПРАВКИ КОММЕНТОВ-->
<form action="{% url 'articles:AddComment_inChat' b.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id = 'input_name' type = 'text' required placeholder="Введите имя", name = 'name'><br><br>
<textarea name="text" required placeholder="Текст комментария" id="input_comment_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<button id = 'input_button' type = 'submit'>Добавить комментарий</button>
</form>
```

Вот ошибка:

Exception Type: AttributeError

Exception Value:'Chat' object has no attribute 'comment_set'

Comment: Пожалуйста, уберите лишнее использование верхнего регистра символов. Сообщения в верхнем регистре выглядят как крик.

Comment: В смысле?Можете конкретнее указать,где мне надо исправить,пожалуйста!

Comment: Добавьте оригинальный текст ошибки в свой вопрос.

Comment: Сейчас,добавлю текст ошибки

Comment: Добавил в конце вопроса

Comment: Вы что, текст ошибки перевели на русский?

Comment: ой блин автоматом перевело,вам на английском дать?

Comment: Все добавил на английском,но это не вся ошибка,ну там просто остальной текст - не нужный

Comment: И что делать?Почему не добавляются комменты?

Comment: Это не полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Модель `Comment` не имеет внешнего ключа на модель `Chat`, поэтому у экземпляров `Chat` нет `comment_set`.

Comment: т.е для класса chat мне нужно прописать ForeignKey и связать его с классом Comment?

Comment: Нет, классу Comment надо прописать ForeignKey на Chat.

Comment: Ну да,я перепутал,щас попробую!

Comment: Для модели коммент ForeignKey это Article,а два ForeignKey писать нельзя.И что делать,я не знаю(

Comment: Читать документацию про generic relation.