# Почему comment_set не является атрибутом проекта?

Tags: python, django

Вот у меня есть модели Article и Comment(первая это типо статьи,вторая это комменты к статьям),вот эти модели(файл models.py):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField("название статьи",max_length = 60)
    article_text = models.TextField("текст статьи",max_length = 3000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("дата публикации")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title
    
    
    def date(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))

    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статья'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'

#Комменты к статьям 
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 50)
    comment_text = models.CharField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Вот urls приложения:

```
path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
path('<int:article_id>/add_comment/', views.add_comment, name = 'add_comment'),
```

А вот иx views.py

```
#Для отображения Статей
def detail(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)  
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')    

    test2 = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]

    return render(request,'articles/detail.html',{'article': a, 'test2': test2})

#Для отображения Комментов
def add_comment(request,article_id):
    try:    
        a = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)  
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')
    a.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])    

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('articles:detail', args = (a.id,)))
```

А вот шаблон detai.html в котором отображаются статьи и комменты:

```
<h1 id = article_title>{{article.article_title}}</h1>

<h2 id = article_text>{{article.article_text}}</h2>

<em id = article_pubdate>{{article.pub_date}}</em> 




<!--ОТОБРАЖЕНИЕ КОММЕНТОВ-->

{% if test2 %}
     {% for c in test2  %}
    <p>
        <strong id = name_comment>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
        <p id = comment_text_article>{{c.comment_text}}</p>
    {% endfor  %}    
    </p>
{% else %}
<h2 id = 'comment_notfound_text'>Комментарии не найдены,станьте первым :)</h2> 
{% endif %}

<!--КНОПКИ ОТПРАВКИ КОММЕНТОВ-->
<form action="{% url 'articles:add_comment' article.id %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}
<input id = 'input_name' type = 'text' required placeholder="Введите имя", name = 'name'><br><br>
<textarea name="text" required placeholder="Текст комментария" id="input_comment_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<button id = 'input_button' type = 'submit'>Добавить комментарий</button>
</form>
```

ТОЕСТЬ ВСЕ КОММЕНТЫ ОТОБРАЖАЮТСЯ И ДОБАВЛЯЮТСЯ НОРМАЛЬНО

Так вот,а теперь про ошибку...
Я создал 2 модели(они похожи на предыдущие модели) - Chat и Chat_text_add( я хотел сделать чат на сайте с добавлением комментов)
При добавлении коммента выскакивает ошибка что типо у обьекта Chat нет атрибута comment_set,почему его нету?И как это исправить?
Вот модели(models.py)

```
#Чат
class Chat(models.Model):
    title_chat = models.CharField("Название чата",max_length = 60)  
    chat_text = models.TextField("Описание чата", max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_chat

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Чат'

#Добавление комментов к чату
class Chat_text_add(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 30)
    comment_text = models.TextField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Добавление комментов к чату'
```

Вот еще urls приложения:

```
path('<int:article_id_chat>',views.chat1,name = 'chat1'),
path('<int:article_id_chat>/AddComment_inChat',views.AddComment_inChat,name = 'AddComment_inChat')
```

Вот views.py :

```
def chat1(request,article_id_chat):
    try:
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = article_id_chat)
    except:
        raise Http404('Комменты в чате не найдены')  
    test3 = b.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request,'articles/detail2.html',{'b': b,'title':'Заголовок','test3':test3})  

def AddComment_inChat(request,article_id_chat):
    try:
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = article_id_chat)
    except:
        raise Http404('Комменты в чате не найдены')    
    
    b.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])     
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('articles:detail2', args = (b.id,)))
```

И вот шаблон для отображения чата (detail2.html):

```
<h1 id = article_title>{{b.title_chat}}</h1>

<h2 id = article_text>{{b.chat_text}}</h2>



{% if test3 %}
     {% for i in test3  %}
    <p>
        <strong id = name_comment>{{i.author_name}}</strong>
        <p id = comment_text_article>{{i.comment_text}}</p>
    {% endfor  %}    
    </p>
{% else %}
<h2 id = 'comment_notfound_text'>Комментарии не найдены,станьте первым :)</h2> 
{% endif %}


<!--КНОПКИ ОТПРАВКИ КОММЕНТОВ-->
<form action="{% url 'articles:AddComment_inChat' b.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id = 'input_name' type = 'text' required placeholder="Введите имя", name = 'name'><br><br>
<textarea name="text" required placeholder="Текст комментария" id="input_comment_text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
<button id = 'input_button' type = 'submit'>Добавить комментарий</button>
</form>
```

VIEWS (новое)

```
def detail2(request):
    try:
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = 1)  
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')
    
    test3 =  b.chat_text_add_set.order_by('-id')[:10]    
    return render  (request,'articles/detail2.html',{'b': b,'test3': test3})   

def ChatTextAdd(request):
    try:    
        b = Chat.objects.get(id = 1)      
    except:
        raise Http404('Статьи не найдены')
    b.comment_set.create(author_name = request.POST['name'],comment_text = request.POST['text'])    

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse ('articles:detail2', args = (b.id,)))
```

МОДЕЛИ:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    title_chat = models.CharField("Название чата",max_length = 60)      
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_chat

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Чат'


class ChatTextAdd(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 50)
    comment_text = models.CharField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комменты к чату'
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Выскакивает ошибка У объекта нет атрибута “comment_set”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166304/204271)

Comment: Я этого со 2 акк пишу!Потому что никто не отвечает

Answer (score 0):

У экземпляра класса `Chat` (`b`) нету связанной модели `Comment`, по этой причине, `b.comment_set` не выводит комментарии!

models.py:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    title_chat = models.CharField("Название чата",max_length = 60)  
    chat_text = models.TextField("Описание чата", max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_chat

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Чат'

#Добавление комментов к чату
class ChatTextAdd(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField("имя автора ", max_length = 30)
    comment_text = models.TextField("текст комментария", max_length = 500)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Добавление комментов к чату'
```

views.py:

```
 b.chattextadd_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Comment: Я создал класс с ChatTextAdd(посмотрите в ответе) и у него в ForeignKey прописан Chat,во views я этого все дело вывожу(посмотрите в ответе),написал как вы сказали и выскакивает ошибка У объекта Chat нет атрибута chat_text_add_set

Comment: @Miha_Taras Так раз вы переименовали класс в `ChatTextAdd` то и запрашивать нужно `chattextadd_set` <- Так вы пробовали?

Comment: Запрашивать что,откуда?Я просто не понимаю,новичок,еще глупый так сказать...

Comment: @Miha_Taras Изменил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Сейчас попробую!

Comment: Кидает мне 404 ошибку

Comment: @Miha_Taras Вы статьи удаляли? В функции вы берете запись с `id = 1`. Возможно такой записи несуществует!

Comment: Нет,у меня есть одна,ну т.е я обращаюсь к Chat.object.get(id = 1),а у меня есть 1 созданный чат

Comment: Я сейчас зашел в админку(хотел зайти в чат) и выдало ошибку: 
такого столбца нет: article_chat.chat_text

Comment: @Miha_Taras Вы после того как изменили название модели, миграции делали??? `./manage.py makemigrations` и `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Нет,не делал,но зашел в бд(с помощью squlatestuidio,как-то так) и там названия все тежи что и в моделях

Comment: @Miha_Taras `Chat.objects.get(id=1)` Это не говорит о том, что у вас есть только одна запись! Это говорит о том, что вы хотите взять запись по `id` равному 1! Это не одно и тоже.

Comment: @Miha_Taras Почти при любом изменении моделей, нужно делать миграции!

Comment: При python manage.py makemigrations выдает это:You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'chat_text' to chat without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

Comment: @Miha_Taras Слушайте, гугл вам на что? Просто берете и вставляете туда ошибку, после того как исправите баги и сделаете миграции, напишите!

Comment: Пока что не смогу,у меня срочные дела,если что(может быть)напишу вечером